# Is studying while sick bad for your brain?

Tags: environmental-health, learning

The New Straits Times [reported](http://findarticles.com/p/news-articles/new-straits-times/mi_8016/is_20100131/12-steps-damage-brain/ai_n48859421/):

> Working unduly hard or studying while sick may lead to a decrease in effectiveness of the brain as well as damaging it.

[P-Healthcare blog](http://phealth-care.blogspot.com/2010/07/top-ten-brain-damaging-habits.html) reports one of the "Top ten brain-damaging habits":

> Do you know that working hard or studying while sick leads to a decrease of brain effctiveness (sic) and also brings brain damage? Well, now you know

[WeeklyShack](http://www.weeklyshack.com/habits.html) web-site reports:

> Working your brain during illness: Working hard or studying while sick may lead to a decrease in
>   sharpness of the brain as well as damage the brain.

Is there any evidence that studying while sick causing any form of brain-damage?

Comment: I added several cites to demonstrate notability, and re-opened. I note all the wording is similar - common source material?

Comment: To Oddthinking " How do you know it is about TCM? " I wrote what author wrote about what cause damage "Because: Evening at 9 – 11pm : is the time for eliminating unnecessary/ toxic chemicals (de-toxification) from the antibody system (lymph nodes). This time duration should be spent by relaxing or listening to music. If during this time a housewife is still in an unrelaxed state such as washing the dishes or monitoring children doing their homework, this will have a negative impact on her health"
http://knowfood.cn/en/events/dont-sleep-too-late-liver-damage-2/
I dont wrote this is source but t